# I can find if 1 number is a krishnamoorthy number or not but I need to find for 10 numbers

Tags: java

Krishnamoorthy number is a number whose sum of the factorial of digits is equal to the number itself. (Ex : 145 = 1! + 4! + 5!)
My current program can find if a single number is a krishnamoorthy number or not, but I am trying to accept 10 numbers and display which of them are krishnamoorthy number or not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class krishnamoorthy {
  static int fact(int number)   
    {   
        int f = 1;   
        while (number != 0) {   
            f = f * number;   
            number--;   
        }   
        return f;   
    }   
    static boolean checkNumber(int number)   
    {   
        int sum = 0;                
        int tempNumber = number;     
        while (tempNumber != 0) {   
            sum = sum + fact(tempNumber % 10);   
            tempNumber = tempNumber / 10;   
        }   
        if(sum == number)  
            return true;  
        else  
            return false;  
    }   
  
    public static void main(String[] args)   
    {   
        int n;   
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);   
        System.out.println("Enter any number:");    
        n = sc.nextInt();           
        if (checkNumber(n))   
            System.out.println(n + " is a krishnamurthy number");   
        else  
            System.out.println(n + "is not a krishnamurthy number");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a loop over the input and add the values to an array and then check each number in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class krishnamoorthy {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many numbers: ");
        int total = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.format("Enter %d numbers:\n", total);

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            int num = scan.nextInt();

            if (isKrishnamoorthy(num))
                System.out.format("%d is a krishnamurthy number\n", num);
            else
                System.out.format("%d is not a krishnamurthy number\n", num);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isKrishnamoorthy(int num) {
        int sum = num;

        while (num != 0) {
            sum -= fact(num % 10);
            num /= 10;
        }

        return sum == 0;
    }

    private static int fact(int num) {
        int res = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++)
            res *= i;

        return res;
    }

}
```